# Interpolation with single quotes

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript code inside an .erb file in Ruby on Rails:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

...

function show_all_categories_terms_contents() {
  $('#categories_terms_root2').show();
  $('#categories_terms_root3').show();

...

</script>
```

I need to perform a loop to create as many `#categories_terms_root` as I need, instead of adding a new line for each one.

I tried various things, but none worked for me:

```
function show_all_categories_terms_contents() {
  for(int i=2; i<=6; i++)
    $(String.concat("#categories_terms_root", i)).show();

}
```

Comment: This isn't really a Ruby or Rails question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you have several errors in your js code. Following code should work:

```
function show_all_categories_terms_contents() {
  for(var i=2; i<=6; i++){
    $("#categories_terms_root" + i).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer but you don't need to check `element.length`...just call `show()` on the element and if the element doesn't actually exist, it doesn't matter; jQuery will just ignore the call to `show()`.

Comment: I deleted my other comment. The code was failing because I forgot one parentheses. Thanks, it really works ^^

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways of solving the problem:

- Have a container element e.g. a div with ID `categories_terms_container`, then you can do `$('#categories_terms_container').children().each(function() { $(this).show(); });`
- Use classes, e.g. `<div id="categories_terms_root2" class="categories_terms_root">` and use the class selector: `$('.categories_terms_root').each(...)`
- Use the "attribute starts with" selector, e.g. `$('[id^=categories_terms]').each(...)`

The third option is the least efficient.